# JavaScript - Background change with CSS Class and setInterval method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new with JavaScript and I would like to make an automatic background changer with timed intervals and CSS class changes. At the moment my code doesn't cycle two backgrounds as intended. Can you guys check what's wrong with it?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var switcher = 0;

  var counter = setInterval(count, 2000);

  function count() {
    switcher = switcher + 1;
    if (switcher >= 2) {
      switcher = 0;
      return;
    };
  };


  switch (switcher) {

    case 0:
      $("#main-content").removeClass("background1");
      $("#main-content").addClass("background3");
      break;

    case 1:
      $("#main-content").removeClass("background3");
      $("#main-content").addClass("background1");
      break;


  };
});
```

Comment: Move the `switch` block into the `count()` function... By the way, your current increment and if test can be replaced with `switcher = (switcher + 1) % 2`. But if there are only two possible options you could just use a boolean.

Comment: Add html snippet..

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `switch()` statement into interval function callback. remove `return` as well.

```
function count() {
    switcher = switcher + 1;
    if (switcher >= 2) {
      switcher = 0;
    };
    switch (switcher) {

        case 0:
          $("#main-content").removeClass("background1");
          $("#main-content").addClass("background3");
          break;

        case 1:
          $("#main-content").removeClass("background3");
          $("#main-content").addClass("background1");
          break;
    };

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), it's much cleaner:

```
$(function () {
    var switcher = 0;
    var counter = setInterval(count, 2000);

    function count() {
        $("#main-content").toggleClass("background1 background3")
    };
});
```

**Just make sure you assign a default class to the div:**

```
<div id="main-content" class="background1">

</div>
```